# Does there always exist $x \geq \sup X-\epsilon$ for $x \in X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ for all $\epsilon>0$?

Tags: real-analysis

I was looking over an exercise regarding monotonic series and the autor used the argument that for a non decreasing sequence $(x_n)$ there is an element $x \in (x_n)$ such that $x_n \geq sup (x_n)-\epsilon$, I can't find any counter example for it. This question also came from my previous deleted question.

Comment: Yes, it does. Prove by contradiction.

Comment: This is no good if $\sup X = +\infty$.  Also, if $X = \varnothing$ then $\sup X = -\infty$, also no good.  But it does work if $\sup X \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - suppose for a contradiction there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that $x < sup(X) - \epsilon$ for all $x \in X$. Then we have an upper bound of $sup(X) - \epsilon < sup(X)$ for elements of $X$, contradicting the supremum as the least upper bound.

Comment: sorry, take $X=\{1,2\}$, $supX=2$, $\epsilon=0.01$

Comment: I think you are confused. 2>1.99, this is not a counterexample.

Comment: xD ..............